# A puzzle about ERIC

Tags: cipher, geography

This is a puzzle about (7, 8, 8), or ERIC for short. Can you decode them?

IM[K]N, OPQFR
ABNP, AC
V R[K]T, U R[K]T
HIJK L, HIJK
JPFH, SFH
NPFJ L, NP[J]F
V D, EF GF

ERIC = ??P??[K] [J]?GFP ?[N]??[K]R

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This puzzle is about ...

> ... **Central American capitals**.

Some observations first:

> - The letters are just enumerated from A to V.
> - The enumeration of the answer suggests three words with 7, 8 and 8 letters, but the given pattern is (6, 5, 6). (If bracketed letters are counted as one entity.) So it is likely that some letters represent more than one letter, perhaps a syllable.
> - Some letters are in brackets. Let's treat them as separate entities for now, put it seems likely that for example [K] is a variation on K, perhaps a multi-letter combo without its first or last letter.
> - There is [geography](/questions/tagged/geography) tag and each line is in the format *something*, *something else*, which suggests the common *city*, *country* format.

A first assumption:

> If the lines are in *city*, *country* format, the line **V R**[**K**]**T, U R**[**K**]**T**. The seconds words are the same, but the first is different. **San Salvador, El Salvador** comes to mind as an example for this pattern. Perhaps we can assign letters to syllables:
>
>  **V R**[**K**]**T** = san sal-va-dor
>  **U R**[**K**]**T** = el sal-va-dor
>
>  There's another city starting with **V**: **V D**. Let's make another assumption, namely that the cities must be capital cities. There isn't really anything that suggests that, but capitals of countries are a common topic of knowledge puzzles and the countries, if that's what the term after the comma is, are all different.
>
>  There aren't a lot of [capitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_capitals) that start with "San". Let's ignore San Marino, San Marino, because the country **EF GF** is sufficiently different from the city **V D** here. Let's also discount Puerto Rico, because it isn't an independent country, even if it conveniently has two words. Instead, let's go with:
>
>  **V D** = san jose
>  **EF GF** = cos-ta ri-ca
>
>  If that's true, **F** is both ta and ca. Well, never mind. Let's go with that for now and get back to it later.
>
>  Another interesting line is **HIJK L, HIJK**, where city and country differ by an appended word. That suggests Mexico (City), Guatemala (City) or Panama (City). The two decoded lines above are countries in Central America as are Guatemala and Panama. And there's a second city that ends in **L**, even if the first word is slightly different for city and country.

Taking this further:

> Well, it turns out thet **HIJK L** = gua-te-ma-la city. The assumption that a letter represents a syllable is wrong. Instead, a letter represents a chunk of any length. The **K** in Guatemala is "la" and [**K**] in Salvador is "al", so brackets reverse the chunk.
>
>  Next we can see that **NPFJ** = pa-n-a-ma and **NP**[**J**]**F** = pa-n-[am]-a are two different representations for the same word.
>
>  Anyway, I think the theme and possible decodings are established now and the messages decode to:
>
> ```
>      I  M    [K]  N          O  P Q   F R
>      te-guci-[al]-pa         ho-n-dur-a-s
>
>      A  B  N   P             A  C
>      be-lm-opa-n             be-lize
>
>      V   R [K] T             U  R [K]  T
>      san s-[al]-vador        el s-[al]-vador
>
>      H   I  J  K  L          H   I  J  K
>      gua-te-ma-la city       gua-te-ma-la
>
>      J  P F H                S     F H
>      ma-n-a-gua              nicar-a-gua
>
>      N  P F J  L             N  P [J]  F
>      pa-n-a-ma city          pa-n-[am]-a
>
>      V   D                   E    F G   F
>      san jose                cost-a ric-a
> ```

The answer phrase:

> With the decodings found above, the phrase
>
>  • • **P** • • [**K**]   [**J**] • **GFP**    • [**N**] • • [**K**]**R**
>
>  can be translated to:
>
>  • •-n-• •-al    [am]-•-ric-a-n    •-[ap]-• •-[al]-s
>
>  The blanks are easily replaced and we find the topical **Central American Capitals**.

Who is ERIC?

> Translating **ERIC** in the same way yields cos-s-te-lize, which doesn't look very useful.
>
>  ERIC is crypric-crossword speak for "Central America": (AM)**ERIC**(A). And it is written in all capitals, so ERIC is just another way to say **Central American Capitals**.

Comment: I'm curious if there were other options for your first step.  None come immediately to mind.